# How to vertically align an image inside a div with dynamic height?

Tags: jquery, html, css, height, vertical-alignment

What we have is a div that contains an image that a user uploads. This is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container_img">
    <img height="120" width="150" src="[image name].jpg">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.container_img {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Our problem is if the image the user uploads has a height smaller than 150px, there's a big space at the bottom. So we want to vertically align the image so that it doesn't look like it's just floating.

I've tried searching for solutions on the net but I can't find one that works with dynamic images inside a DIV. Some solutions require that you know the dimensions of the image.

Has anybody had this problem and solved it?

Comment: Possible with pure CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474#18516474

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use JavaScript/jQuery to detect image height. CSS is not a dynamic language and you cannot detect height using pure css. Using jQuery you can do

**jQuery**

```
var $img = $('div.container_img img');
var h = $img.height();
$img.css('margin-top', + h / -2 + "px"); //margin-top should be negative half of image height. This will center the image vertically when combined with position:absolute and top:50%.
```

**CSS**

```
div.container_img {
    position:relative; 
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
}

div.container_img img{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/nQ4uu/2/

Comment: Thanks for the code but when I tried it on HTML, it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something on the jQuery script? I surrounded it with <script type="text/javascript"></script>.

Comment: You also need to include the jQuery script `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: I already included the jQuery library but it still doesn't work. This is the entire jQuery code: <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> var $img = $('div.container_img img'); var h = $img.height(); $img.css('margin-top', +h / -2 + "px"); </script>

Comment: Ok, nevermind my previous question. Apparently, it's because I placed the script inside the <head></head> tag. I should've placed it outside the body tag. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
div.container_img {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /* other attributes */
}
```

works but I'm not sure if it does on all IE versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't be able to align the image vertically using any straight forward technique. You can see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/naveedbutt/UGYFF/41/) for aligning the image horizontally though...

Answer (score 0):

it is not that easy, check out this page http://www.vdotmedia.com/demo/css-vertically-center.html

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using flex in css:

```
div.container_img {
    position:flex; 
     width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    justify-content: center;
}

div.container_img img{
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I know this is an old question but i think there i s abetter answer with CSS alone

DEMO [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/TMwBE/1/)

HTML

```
 <div id="centered"></div>
```

CSS

```
#centered {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

That's it!