# Vertically align an image inside a div with responsive height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

I have the following code which sets up a container which has a height that changes with the width when the browser is re-sized (to maintain a square aspect ratio).

HTML

```
<div class="responsive-container">
    <div class="dummy"></div>
    <div class="img-container">
        <IMG HERE>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.responsive-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.dummy {
    padding-top: 100%; /* forces 1:1 aspect ratio */
}

.img-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

How can I vertically align the IMG inside the container? All my images have variable heights and the container can't have a fixed height/line height because it's responsive... Please help!

Comment: Here is a simple flexbox solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977476/3597276

Answer (score 393, accepted):

Here is a technique to align inline elements inside a *parent*, horizontally and vertically at the same time:

## Vertical Alignment

**1)** In this approach, we create an `inline-block` (pseudo-)element as the first (or last) child of the *parent*, and set its `height` property to `100%` to take all the height of its *parent*.

**2)** Also, adding `vertical-align: middle` keeps the inline(-block) elements at the middle of the line space. So, we add that CSS declaration to the *first-child* and *our element* (the *image*) both.

**3)** Finally, in order to remove the white space character between *inline(-block)* elements, we could set the font size of the *parent* to zero by `font-size: 0;`.

**Note:** I used Nicolas Gallagher's [image replacement technique](http://nicolasgallagher.com/another-css-image-replacement-technique/) in the following.

### What are the benefits?

- The container (*parent*) can have dynamic dimensions.
- There's no need to specify the dimensions of the image element explicitly.
- We can easily use this approach to [align a `<div>` element vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533287/vertical-center-with-css/21534465#21534465) as well; which may have a dynamic content (height and/or width). But note that you have to re-set the `font-size` property of the `div` to display the inside text. **[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/VsakD/8/)**.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="element"> ... </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;  /* align the inline(-block) elements horizontally */
    font: 0/0 a;         /* remove the gap between inline(-block) elements */
}

.container:before {    /* create a full-height inline block pseudo=element */
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;  /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
    height: 100%;
}

#element {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;  /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
    font: 16px/1 Arial sans-serif;        /* <-- reset the font property */
}
```

### The output

[image: Vertically align an element in its container]

## Responsive Container

This section is not going to answer the question as the OP already knows how to create a responsive container. However, I'll explain how it works.

In order to make the *height* of a container element changes with its *width* (respecting the aspect ratio), we could use a percentage value for top/bottom `padding` property.

*A [percentage value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434053/position-absolute-top-property-based-on-the-parent-width/21434501#21434501) on top/bottom padding or margins is relative to the width of the containing block.*

For instance:

```css
.responsive-container {
  width: 60%;

  padding-top: 60%;    /* 1:1 Height is the same as the width */
  padding-top: 100%;   /* width:height = 60:100 or 3:5        */
  padding-top: 45%;    /* = 60% * 3/4 , width:height =  4:3   */
  padding-top: 33.75%; /* = 60% * 9/16, width:height = 16:9   */
}
```

Here is the **[Online Demo](http://jsbin.com/jodevaga/1/edit)**. Comment out the lines from the bottom and resize the panel to see the effect.

Also, we could apply the `padding` property to a *dummy* child or `:before`/`:after` pseudo-element to achieve the same result. But **note** that in this case, the percentage value on `padding` is relative to the *width* of the `.responsive-container` itself.

```html
<div class="responsive-container">
  <div class="dummy"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.responsive-container { width: 60%; }

.responsive-container .dummy {
  padding-top: 100%;    /*  1:1 square */
  padding-top: 75%;     /*  w:h =  4:3 */
  padding-top: 56.25%;  /*  w:h = 16:9 */
}
```

**[Demo #1](http://jsbin.com/qatuyuye/1/edit)**.
**[Demo #2](http://jsbin.com/qatuyuye/2/edit)** *(Using `:after` pseudo-element)*

### Adding the content

Using `padding-top` property [causes a huge space](http://jsbin.com/qatuyuye/5/edit) at the top or bottom of the content, inside the *container*.

In order to fix that, we have wrap the content by a wrapper element, remove that element from document normal flow by using [absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), and finally expand the wrapper (bu using `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` properties) to fill the entire space of its parent, the *container*.

Here we go:

```css
.responsive-container {
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
}

.responsive-container .wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Here is the **[Online Demo](http://jsbin.com/qatuyuye/6/edit)**.

---

## Getting all together

```html
<div class="responsive-container">
  <div class="dummy"></div>

  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.img-container {
  text-align:center; /* Align center inline elements */
  font: 0/0 a;       /* Hide the characters like spaces */
}

.img-container:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

.img-container img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is the **[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/46psK/)**.

Obviously, you could avoid using `::before` pseudo-element for **browser compatibility**, and create an element as the first child of the `.img-container`:

```html
<div class="img-container">
    <div class="centerer"></div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
</div>
```

```css
.img-container .centerer {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/46psK/3/)**.

### Using `max-*` properties

In order to keep the image inside of the box in lower width, you could set `max-height` and `max-width` property on the image:

```
.img-container img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 100%;  /* <-- Set maximum height to 100% of its parent */
    max-width: 100%;   /* <-- Set maximum width to 100% of its parent */
}
```

Here is the **[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/46psK/4/)**.

Comment: Hi, Thank you! I had a problem with image (width over container) because I set letter-spacing to every element. `letter-spacing:0!important;` resolved my issue.

Comment: It doesn't work when the image is bigger than the container. That's why on mobile it may appear differently...

Comment: The `inline-block` trick is neat.  If the image is or may be bigger than the container, you can give it a negative margin.

Answer (score 50):

With flexbox this is easy:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/rqa3d6L6/1/)**

Just add the following to the image container:

```
.img-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex; /* add */
    justify-content: center; /* add to align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* add to align vertical */
}
```

Comment: This solution works and is much more elegant in my case. CSS3 Flex is awesome!

Comment: It doesn't work in Safari :( I guess the problem is flex

Comment: @yennefer for safari use `-webkit-` prefix, or try a library like prefixfree.js :)

Comment: This doesn't work when the height of the container is responsive (in percent).

Answer (score 16):

Use this css, as you already have the markup for it:

```
.img-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

.img-container > img {
  margin-top:-50%;
  margin-left:-50%;  
}
```

Here is a working JsBin: http://jsbin.com/ihilUnI/1/edit

This solution only works for square images (because a percentage margin-top value depends on the width of the container, not the height). For random-size images, you can do the following:

```
.img-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* add browser-prefixes */
}
```

Working JsBin solution: http://jsbin.com/ihilUnI/2/edit

Comment: Sorry, not working for me - this is just reducing the size of the images to half the width of the container.

Comment: I don't see how that can happen from the CSS i mentioned. Please provide a working sample i can see so i can improve my answer.
PS: I also provided another solution :)

Answer (score 12):

You can center an image, both horizontally and vertically, using `margin: auto` and absolute positioning. Also:

1. It is possible to ditch extra markup by using pseudo elements.
2. It is possible to display the middle portion of LARGE images by using negative left, top, right and bottom values.

```css
.responsive-container {
  margin: 1em auto;
  min-width: 200px;       /* cap container min width */
  max-width: 500px;       /* cap container max width */
  position: relative;     
  overflow: hidden;       /* crop if image is larger than container */
  background-color: #CCC; 
}
.responsive-container:before {
  content: "";            /* using pseudo element for 1:1 ratio */
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
.responsive-container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -999px;            /* use sufficiently large number */
  bottom: -999px;
  left: -999px;
  right: -999px;
  margin: auto;           /* center horizontally and vertically */
}
```

```html
<p>Note: images are center-cropped on &lt;400px screen width.
  <br>Open full page demo and resize browser.</p>
<div class="responsive-container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/9/">
</div>
<div class="responsive-container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/8/">
</div>
<div class="responsive-container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/400/sports/7/">
</div>
<div class="responsive-container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/6/">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! your .responsive-container img css was the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one

```
  .responsive-container{
          display:table;
  }
  .img-container{
          display:table-cell;
          vertical-align: middle;
   }
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work, I think because my `.img-container` is absolutely positioned - this is necessary to keep the square aspect ratio/dynamic height.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a technique that allows you to center ANY content both vertically and horizontally!

Basically, you just need a two containers and make sure your elements meet the following criteria.

### The outher container :

- should have `display: table;`

### The inner container :

- should have `display: table-cell;`
- should have `vertical-align: middle;`
- should have `text-align: center;`

### The content box :

- should have `display: inline-block;`

If you use this technique, just add your image (along with any other content you want to go with it) to the content box.

### **Demo :**

```css
body {
    margin : 0;
}

.outer-container {
    position : absolute;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
}

.inner-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.centered-content {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    padding : 12px;
    border : 1px solid #000;
}

img {
   max-width : 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
   <div class="inner-container">
     <div class="centered-content">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRsBv.png" />
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WXLsY/623/)!

Answer (score 2):

I came across this thread in search of a solution that:

- uses 100% of the given image's width
- keeps the image aspect ratio
- keeps the image vertically aligned to the middle
- works in browsers that do not fully support flex

Testing *some* of the solutions posted above I didn't find one to meet all of this criteria, so I put together this simple one which might be useful for other people needing to do the same:

```css
.container {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid turquoise;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.container:last-of-kind {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 70%;
  /* this is the desired aspect ratio */
  width: 100%;
}

.image-container img {
  position: absolute;
  /* the following 3 properties center the image on the vertical axis */
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  /* uses image at 100% width (also meaning it's horizontally center) */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x800" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x800" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x800" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
</div>
```

Working example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/badfreja/utsnbxxg/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

Html

```
<div class="responsive-container">
     <div class="img-container">
         <IMG HERE>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
height:0;
padding-bottom:100%;
}
.img-container img {
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html code

`<div class="image-container">
    <img src=""/>
   </div>`

css code

```
img
{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
 }
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Make another div and add both 'dummy' and 'img-container' inside the div

Do HTML and CSS like follows

```css
html , body {height:100%;}
.responsive-container { height:100%; display:table; text-align:center; width:100%;}
.inner-container {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
  <div class="dummy">Sample</div>
  <div class="img-container">
   Image tag
  </div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Instead of 100% for the 'responsive-container' you can give the height that you want.,