# aligning contents of div to center

Tags: jquery, css, html, alignment

I have a problem in aligning the contents of the div to center

I have tried a lot of thing to center the images but did not work.

I have the following structure

```
<div class="middleSlideContents">
    <div class='image'>
       <img>
    </div>
    <div class='image'>
       <img>
    </div>
    <div class='image'>
       <img>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i just have to align the contents of `<div class='middleSlideContents'>` to center but i can't figure out what i am doing wrong.

The `<div class='image'>` are generated dynamically but when it generates it has the following structure.

Rest of the code is here [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/7w8TC/12/)

and the `middleSlideContents` div is a responsive so the heights and widths varry by screen right now it is not in jiddle demo

Any help please, please tell if the structure is wrong or i am doing something wrong

Comment: use text-align:center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could display the `div.image` elements as `inline-block`, then use `test-align-center` for the parent (`.middleSlideContents`) to align the div(s) elements center horizontally:

```css
.image {
    /* Other styles...  */
    display: inline-block;
}

.middleSlideContents {
    text-align: center;  /* <-- align the inline(-block) elements horizontally */
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/7w8TC/13/)**

### Update

In order to align the `inline-block` boxes vertically, you follow **[this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474#18516474)**:

```css
.image {
    /* Other styles...  */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.middleSlideContents:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/7w8TC/19/)**

Comment: And remove the `float: left;` property from the `.image` divs.

Comment: In fact, you removed it in your fiddle, without this the example doesn't work. If something is `float: left` then it can't react to the `text-align: center` property of its parent.

But, why you say it crashes the layout?

Comment: @davidgnin `In fact, you removed it in your fiddle` No I didn't. The second statement is not true too, `float: left` is applied to the parent itself, but `text-align: center` will be applied to the children.

Comment: I think its a misunderstanding. I was refering to the `float: left` in `.image` divs, not in the `.middleSlideContents`.

Comment: @davidgnin Oh I see, Sorry I was under this assumption that it is obvious to remove `float` property when using `inline-block` at a same time :)

Answer (score 1):

remove `float` and then add 2 lines in your css as below :

```
.middleSlideContents
{
    width: 86%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 7px;
    text-align:center; /*added */
}

.image
{
    /* height: 80%; */
    /* width: 16.2%; */
    border-radius: 5px;
    display:inline-block; /*added */
    margin-right:5px;
    border:1px solid;
}
```

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7w8TC/14/)

**EDIT**

To **center vertically** use `table-cell`

```
.middleSlideContents
{
    width: 86%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 7px;
    text-align:center;
    display:table; /* make parent div behave as a table */
    table-layout:fixed;
}

.image
{
    border-radius: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:5px;
    display:table-cell; /* make child as a table-cell*/
    vertical-align:middle; /*vertical middle align*/
}
```

[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7w8TC/18/)

Comment: but what about vertically aligning it to center?

Answer (score 1):

here is demo of horizontal center align

- http://jsfiddle.net/jkkheni/7w8TC/20/

  ```
  .middleSlideContents
  {
    width: 86%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 7px;
    text-align:center;
    display:table; 
   }

    .image
   {
       /* height: 80%; */
       /* width: 16.2%; */
       border-radius: 5px;
       margin-right:5px;
       display:table-cell;
       vertical-align: middle; 

   }
   .image img
   {   
     border:1px solid;
     cursor:pointer;
     width:150px;
     height:150px;

   }
  ```

Comment: @Saurabh edited in demo and code vertical and horizonal center align