# Position absolute top property based on the parent width

Tags: javascript, html, css

Having the following HTML

```
<div class="child-of-body">
    This is a text
</div>
```

and the following CSS

```
.child-of-body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
}
```

I can set the `top` value of the selected elements.
I see that `10%` is computed based on the parent height.

How can I set the `top` property in percent values based on the parent width?

I know that is possible via JavaScript, but would it be possible with CSS only?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JRDe5/)

Comment: Maybe using something like SCSS might work?

Comment: Could you be more elaborative because why generally you worry about top and width.

Comment: Is the `divs` width dynamic or a set size?

Comment: @ArunKumar I am just curious. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for `margin-top` property.

A percentage value on top/bottom `padding` or `margins` is relative to the `width` of the containing block.

```css
.child-of-body {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/JRDe5/4/)**.

Also, it's worth to take a look at **Louis Lazaris' *[Vertical Percentages in CSS](http://www.impressivewebs.com/vertical-percentages-css/)*** article.

Answer (score 1):

try to add `position: relative` for the parent element.

Comment: When I resize the browser window width I want to see the text moving vertically and to have the same aspect ratio.

Comment: I don't think this will work if this is what you need.