# CSS: Center image horizontally and vertically

Tags: css

This is a very common problem, but the technology moves on and new ways of doing this emerge. I'm currently trying to use flexbox for this purpose, but i now have another problem:

- The container i need to center things in is **200x200** pixels (fixed size)
- The image is **unknown aspect ratio** and **unknown size**
- Image size can be higher or lower than the container
- I need to downscale the image so that it is always less or equal to 98% of the container

If the image was square or landscape, i could do max-width: 98%. Is there any way to do the same for the image height?

Comment: whats wrong with `max-height`? Also if you show what you have tried, you might not get downvoted

Comment: @stackErr i know about max-width and max-height, but i don't completely understand them and that's why i ask the question. If i specify both to 98% - will the image scale proportionally?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to show what you want to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically align an image inside a div with responsive height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height)