# How to Vertically center images and text in CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

I have this fiddle here and i want to vertically center the text in the header, the picture in the footer and the picture in the middle which is sticked to the header... I don'T know how to achieve this and i already tried out some things but to no avail. I'll hope for your help here SO (=

Link to the jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/xF6xV/2/

HTML:

```
    <body>      
    <div id="header">        
            <h1>Test Text but it's not inside the actual div...</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="topcontent">
            <img src="http://www.curiousfix.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/only_god_forgives_xxlg-2000x2964.jpg" id="left" >                    
            <img src="http://www.curiousfix.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/only_god_forgives_xxlg-2000x2964.jpg" id="right"/>   
            <img src="http://typographica.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/Lakside-styles-315x165.png" id="mid" />
        </div>
        </br>
        <div id="botcontent">
            <div class="slidercontainer">                      
                <div id="area">
                    <div id="knob"></div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <img src="http://www.duv-ev.de/images/Leiste_Impressum_511x127_rgb-srgb_72.jpg"/>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body,
html {
    height: 98%;
}
#header {
    height: 15.69%;
    background-color: gray;
    line-height:  15.69%;
}

#header h1{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;    
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#content{
    height: 71.16%;
    left:0;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    right:0;       
}
#topcontent{
    height:56.245%; 
}

.slidercontainer{
    width: 100%;
}
#botcontent{
    height: 43.755%;
}

img {
    max-height:100%;
}

#footer{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 13.15%;
}


#left{
    float:left;
    margin-left: 10%;
    max-width: 30%;
}

#right{
    float: right;
    max-width: 30%;
    margin-right:10%;
}
#mid{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 10%;
}

#area {
    background: gray;
    height:6em;
    width: 100%;  
    border-radius: 1em;
}

#knob {      
    height: 6em;
    width: 6em;
    background: orange;
    border-radius: 1em;
}
```

Comment: This can be inspiring: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474#18516474

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xF6xV/4/)**

**The CSS Change:**

```
#header h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay this puts the text in the div but how to center it vertically?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use 3 methods depending upon the use.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/V3L34/)**

1) translate()

2) line-height

3) vertical-align

```
<div id="div1">
    <img src="http://www.curiousfix.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/only_god_forgives_xxlg-2000x2964.jpg"/>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
<div id="div3">
          <img src="http://www.curiousfix.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/only_god_forgives_xxlg-2000x2964.jpg"/>
</div>
```

---

```
#div1, #div2, #div3 {
    display:block;
    margin:20px auto;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
#div1 img {
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
#div2 h1 {
    line-height:200px;
}
#div3 {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#div3 img {
    height:100px;
}
```