# Vertically align ticker text without position absolute and CSS3 transform?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Making a simple ticker, I have a solution that works to vertically align the bar of text, which is the following:

```
tickstream {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color:rgb(64,224,208);
    font-size:61.8vh;
    font-family:"Gill Sans"
}
tickstream span {
    position:absolute;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    top:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(0,-50%);
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:clip;
}
```

See the fiddle here: [http://jsfiddle.net/S6LwG/](http://jsfiddle.net/S6LwG/1/)

How to do this without using `-webkit-translate:transform` ?

This seems overly verbose for just a simple vertical text align. I used to be able to vertically align single lines of text without using `transform` or Chuck Norris, and now I can't figure it out.
*(**Note:** This only needs to work in present Chrome).*

Comment: Do you have to use absolute positioning ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically align an image inside a div with responsive height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple **[pen](http://codepen.io/magnus16/pen/GKcem)** I created for a similar answer. I tried 3 different methods for vertical alignment.

Here is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879621/how-to-vertically-center-images-and-text-in-css/21880016#21880016)

Comment: Thank you. I used the line height. It wasn't working before because I was setting it to the text size, not the container height.