# Vertically align content inside Superslides

Tags: jquery, html, css, vertical-alignment

Im trying to use both Superslides (https://github.com/nicinabox/superslides/) and Boostrap 3 on a site.

It seem to be working quite good, but I need help to vertical align my text content. I have tried position absolute, and fixed, but nothing seems to work.

How should I verticaly align my container, when the content of each slide has a different height?

What it looks like now: http://jsfiddle.net/2P3zL/

my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Slides</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://nicinabox.com/superslides/dist/stylesheets/superslides.css">


</head>
<body>
  <div id="slides">
    <ul class="slides-container">


    <li>
      <img src="http://nicinabox.com/superslides/images/girl.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
            <div class="well">              
                <p>Text 1</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>


    <li>
      <img src="http://nicinabox.com/superslides/images/building.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
            <div class="well">              
                <p>Text 2</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>


    <li>
      <img src="http://nicinabox.com/superslides/images/floor-kid.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="well">
                <h1>Heading 3</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="well">
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table:</td>
                        <th class="text-right">1</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table:</td>
                        <th class="text-right">2</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table:</td>
                        <th class="text-right">3</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table</td>
                        <th class="text-right">4</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table</td>
                        <th class="text-right">5</th>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="well">
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table:</td>
                        <th class="text-right">6</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table</td>
                        <th class="text-right">7</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table</td>
                        <th class="text-right">8</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table</td>
                        <th class="text-right">9</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table</td>
                        <th class="text-right">10</th>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
  </div>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://nicinabox.com/superslides/javascripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://nicinabox.com/superslides/javascripts/jquery.animate-enhanced.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://nicinabox.com/superslides/dist/jquery.superslides.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#slides').superslides({
          animation: 'fade',
          play: 7000,
          pagination: true
        });
    });


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For vertical alignment with unknown dimensions, you can refer to my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474#18516474).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below **CSS**:

```
.container{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.container .row{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
 }
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2P3zL/1/)

---

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2P3zL/3/) in response to the comment / [Fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/2P3zL/3/show/)

Comment: @Alvaro see his fiddle

Comment: Looks great for slide 1 and 2, but a bit wonky on slide 3. Anything I could do to fix it?

Comment: @Garreth00 put heading and table in the 3rd slide in single `<div class="row">...</div>`. Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2P3zL/3/

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you are using is applying inline styles on your generated HTML markup. (on the `li` elements)

You could accomplish it by adding the following styles forcing to overwrite the inline styles with the `!important` clause.

```
.container {
    display: table-cell !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.slides-control li{
    display:table !important;
}
```

Also, you might want to get rid of the `top` and `padding` properties for the `.container` class.