# How to vertically center a container in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I'm looking for a way to vertically center the `container` div inside the `jumbotron` and to set it in the middle of the page.

The `.jumbotron` has to be adapted to the full height and width of the screen. The `.container` div has a width of `1025px` and should be in the middle of the page (vertically center).

I want this page to have the jumbotron adapted to the height and width of the screen along with the container vertically center to the jumbotron. How can I achieve it?

```css
.jumbotron {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
.container {
  width:1025px;
}
.jumbotron .container {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h1>The easiest and powerful way</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                 <div class="top-bg"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5 iPhone-features" style="margin-left:-25px;">
                <ul class="top-features">
                    <li>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-random simple_bg top-features-bg"></i></span>
                        <p><strong>Redirect</strong><br>Visitors where they converts more.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-cogs simple_bg top-features-bg"></i></span>
                        <p><strong>Track</strong><br>Views, Clicks and Conversions.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-check simple_bg top-features-bg"></i></span>
                        <p><strong>Check</strong><br>Constantly the status of your links.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-users simple_bg top-features-bg"></i></span>
                        <p><strong>Collaborate</strong><br>With Customers, Partners and Co-Workers.</p>
                    </li>
                        <a href="pricing-and-signup.html" class="btn-primary btn h2 lightBlue get-Started-btn">GET STARTED</a>
                        <h6 class="get-Started-sub-btn">FREE VERSION AVAILABLE!</h6>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See this on responsive centered columns http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-centered-columns

Comment: http://css-vertical-center.com there are some solutions with browser compatibility information

Comment: Future readers using **Bootstrap 4** and **Bootstrap 5** [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388989/bootstrap-center-vertical-and-horizontal-alignment)

Answer (score 674, accepted):

### The Flexible box way

**Vertical alignment** is now very simple by the use of [Flexible box layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/). Nowadays, this method is supported in a [wide range](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) of web browsers except Internet Explorer 8 & 9. Therefore we'd need to use some hacks/[polyfills](https://github.com/doctyper/flexie) or [different approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height?lq=1) for IE8/9.

In the following I'll show you how to do that in only **3 lines** of text *(regardless of old flexbox syntax)*.

**Note:** it's better to use an additional class instead of altering `.jumbotron` to achieve the vertical alignment. I'd use `vertical-center` class name for instance.

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/ut5sbqvz/)** *(A **[Mirror](http://jsbin.com/namogi/1/edit?css,output)** on jsbin)*.

```
<div class="jumbotron vertical-center"> <!-- 
                      ^--- Added class  -->
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.vertical-center {
  min-height: 100%;  /* Fallback for browsers do NOT support vh unit */
  min-height: 100vh; /* These two lines are counted as one :-)       */

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**Important** notes *(Considered in the demo)*:

1. A *percentage* values of `height` or `min-height` properties is relative to the `height` of the parent element, therefore you should specify the `height` of the parent explicitly.
2. Vendor prefixed / old flexbox syntax omitted in the posted snippet due to brevity, but exist in the online example.
3. In some of old web browsers such as Firefox 9 <sup>(in which I've tested)</sup>, the flex container - `.vertical-center` in this case - won't take the available space inside the parent, therefore we need to specify the `width` property like: `width: 100%`.
4. Also in some of web browsers as mentioned above, the flex item - `.container` in this case - may not appear at the center horizontally. It seems the applied left/right `margin` of `auto` doesn't have any effect on the flex item.
   Therefore we need to align it by `box-pack / justify-content`.

For further details and/or vertical alignment of columns, you could refer to the topic below:

- [vertical-align with Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3/25517025#25517025)

---

### The traditional way for legacy web browsers

This is the old answer I wrote at the time I answered this question. This method has been discussed **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474#18516474)** and it's supposed to work in Internet Explorer 8 and 9 as well. I'll explain it in short:

In inline flow, an inline level element can be aligned vertically to the middle by [`vertical-align: middle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) declaration. Spec from [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align):

> **middle**
>   Align the vertical midpoint of the box with the baseline of the parent box plus half the x-height of the parent.

In cases that the parent - `.vertical-center` element in this case - has an explicit `height`, by any chance if we could have a child element having the exact same `height` of the parent, we would be able [to move the baseline of the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419552/how-to-align-a-label-to-the-bottom-of-a-div-in-css/25419852#25419852) to the midpoint of the full-height child and surprisingly make our desired in-flow child - the `.container` - aligned to the center vertically.

#### Getting all together

That being said, we could create a full-height element within the `.vertical-center` by `::before` or `::after` pseudo elements and also change the default `display` type of it and the other child, the  `.container` to `inline-block`.

Then use `vertical-align: middle;` to align the inline elements vertically.

Here you go:

```
<div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.vertical-center {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;

  text-align: center;  /* align the inline(-block) elements horizontally */
  font: 0/0 a;         /* remove the gap between inline(-block) elements */
}

.vertical-center:before {    /* create a full-height inline block pseudo=element */
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;    /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
  height: 100%;
}

.vertical-center > .container {
  max-width: 100%;

  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;  /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
                           /* reset the font property */
  font: 16px/1 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vuyub/4/edit)**.

Also, to prevent unexpected issues in extra small screens, you can reset the height of the  pseudo-element to `auto` or `0` or change its `display` type to `none` if needed so:

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .vertical-center:before {
    height: auto;
    /* Or */
    display: none;
  }
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vuyub/5/edit)**

And one more thing:

If there are `footer`/`header` sections around the container, it's better to position that elements properly *(`relative`, `absolute`? up to you.)* and add a higher `z-index` value (for assurance) to keep them always on the top of the others.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49064/discussion-between-user1012181-and-hashem-qolami)

Comment: This is all well and good, but as soon as you add `display: flex` to a `.container`, it causes the child `.row`s to flip out. It seems like the flexbox way would therefore require us to forgo using some of the main bootstrap features?

Answer (score 217):

### Update 2021

**Bootstrap 5** still use flexbox, so the methods of vertical centering are the same as Bootstrap 4...

**Bootstrap 4** use flexbox, so the method of vertical centering is much easier and **doesn't require extra CSS**.

Just use the `d-flex` and `align-items-center` utility classes..

```
<div class="jumbotron d-flex align-items-center">
  <div class="container">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/ui6ABmMTLv

**Important:** Vertical centering is **relative to height**. The parent container of the items you're attempting to center *must* have a **defined height**. If you want the height of the page use `vh-100` or `min-vh-100` on the parent! For example:

```
<div class="jumbotron d-flex align-items-center min-vh-100">
  <div class="container text-center">
    I am centered vertically
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252443/vertical-align-center-in-bootstrap-4

Comment: or if `vh` is not the most convenient way, one can also use `min-height-50/75/100...`

Comment: @seedme -- there are no min-height-* classes in Bootstrap

Comment: Excellent, thanks, perhaps make a minimal example, i.e. without `jumbotron` nor even `container` nor `text-center`, since the question is only about vertically alignment

Comment: well done, no css involved!

Answer (score 52):

add Bootstrap.css then add this to your css

```css
   
html, body{height:100%; margin:0;padding:0}
 
.container-fluid{
  height:100%;
  display:table;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
 
.row-fluid {height: 100%; display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle;}
 
 

.centering {
  float:none;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
Now call in your page 

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="centering text-center">
           Am in the Center Now :-)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: html AND body { height: 100%; } is the key

Answer (score 40):

In **[Bootstrap 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/)**:

to ***center the child horizontally***, use bootstrap-4 class:

```
justify-content-center
```

to ***center the child vertically***, use bootstrap-4 class:

```
 align-items-center
```

but remember don't forget to use ***d-flex*** class with these
it's a bootstrap-4 utility class, like so

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height:100px;">
    <span class="bg-primary">MIDDLE</span>    
</div>
```

**Note:** make sure to add bootstrap-4 utilities if this code does not work

I know it's not the direct answer to this question but it may help someone

Comment: This appears to just copy Zim's answer.

Answer (score 8):

My prefered technique :

```
body {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.jumbotron {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

---

#### Demo

```css
body {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.jumbotron {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <h1>The easiest and powerful way</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="top-bg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-5 iPhone-features">
        <ul class="top-features">
          <li>
            <span><i class="fa fa-random simple_bg top-features-bg"></i></span>
            <p><strong>Redirect</strong><br>Visitors where they converts more.</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span><i class="fa fa-cogs simple_bg top-features-bg"></i></span>
            <p><strong>Track</strong><br>Views, Clicks and Conversions.</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span><i class="fa fa-check simple_bg top-features-bg"></i></span>
            <p><strong>Check</strong><br>Constantly the status of your links.</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span><i class="fa fa-users simple_bg top-features-bg"></i></span>
            <p><strong>Collaborate</strong><br>With Customers, Partners and Co-Workers.</p>
          </li>
          <a href="pricing-and-signup.html" class="btn-primary btn h2 lightBlue get-Started-btn">GET STARTED</a>
          <h6 class="get-Started-sub-btn">FREE VERSION AVAILABLE!</h6>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/y69tbpk2/3/)!

Answer (score 8):

Tested in IE, Firefox, and Chrome.

```css
.parent-container {
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.child-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
    <div class="child-container">
        <h2>Header Text</h2>
        <span>Some Text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Found on https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 2):

#### Vertically align center with bootstrap 4

Add this class: `d-flex align-items-center` to the element

#### Example

If you had this:

```
<div class="col-3">
```

change it to this:

```
<div class="col-3 d-flex align-items-center>
```

Answer (score 0):

for [bootstrap4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#justify-content) vertical center of few items

**d-flex** for flex rules

**flex-column** for vertical direction on items

**justify-content-center** for centering

**style='height: 300px;'** must have for set points where center be calc or use **h-100** class

then for horizontal center **div d-flex justify-content-center**
and some container

so we have hierarhy of 3 tag: div-column -> div-row -> div-container

```
     <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center bg-secondary" 
        style="height: 300px;">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
           <div class=bg-primary>Flex item</div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
           <div class=bg-primary>Flex item</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: This appears to just copy Zim's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap 4, you just have to add 2 divs:

```css
.jumbotron{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>    
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="d-table w-100 h-100">
      <div class="d-table-cell w-100 h-100 align-middle">
        <h5>
          your stuff...
        </h5>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <p>
                More stuff...
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The classes: d-table, d-table-cell, w-100, h-100 and align-middle will do the job

Answer (score 0):

Give the container class

```
.container{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
}
```

Give the div that's inside the container:

```
align-content: center;
```

All the content inside this div will show up in the middle of the page.