# Vertical align in bootstrap without breaking the grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know there've been a dozen questions to this problem already but none seems to fit my situation. Since using tables for layouting purposes is no good style, I've tried a different although similar aproach, which seems to be a common way of vertically aligning content inside a div.
I'm using a standard bootstrap grid with a row and columns inside.

```
<div class="row" style="height: 100px";>
    <div class="col-lg-1 valign">
        <img />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 valign">
        <span />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 valign">
        <span />
    </div>
</div>
```

My css looks like this:

```
.valign
{
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}

.valign > img, .valign > span
{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I've seen this been used a lot of times, and I have used it a few times myself, but in bootstrap it breaks the bootstrap grid. The last column 'falls out of the row'.
I've tried adding `table-layout: fixed` to the elements (`span` and `img` in this case) as suggested in another thread.

I've also tried the same thing with twelve `div`s and the class `col-lg-1` with the same result. The last column doesn't seem to fit in the row anymore and it looks like a line break is being created.

Any Ideas?

Cheers, Beejay

Comment: Please provide a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: You may want to consider **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196587/how-to-center-align-vertically-the-container-in-bootstrap/22196760#22196760)** or **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474#18516474)** solutions; Which are the same :) anyway!

Comment: Is your problem that nothing is aligned in a horizontal row? If so, just change `display: table` to `display: inline-table`

Comment: @Hbirjand: I'm trying to sadly, jsfiddle won't accept bootstrap classes at the moment..

Comment: @pattmorter: Too bad, I was hoping it'll be so easy, but the same outcome. Thanks though

Comment: @HashemQolami: I'll give them a try altough it might take a while to implement

Comment: @Beejay, Everything was vertically aligning for me when i changed `display: inline-table` and removed the `height: 100px`. However, my sense of vertically aligned could be different from that of which you are asking.

Comment: @Beejay,May be this tool will do the trick http://www.bootply.com/

Comment: @pattmorter: IMHO aligning vertically means, aligning an element in the middle between top and bottom of the parent element. I would say that's the definition most people use for vertical aligning ;)

Comment: @Hbirjand: Bootply is pretty awesome! [http://www.bootply.com/esbANP4voK] altough I was not able to reproduce the error I'm getting. But to understand the sitation better: the gray div breaks down under the green one

Comment: @HashemQolami: That indeed did the trick! Thank you very much. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: @Beejay I'm glad that it helped. Honestly I don't feel writing an answer right now :/ But if you found those answers helpful, it would be nice if you gave them an upvote :)

Comment: @HashemQolami: As you like ;) I definitely will !