# How to align a label to the "BOTTOM" of a div in CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

DEMO can be found at:

http://www.bootply.com/VZ7gvA7ndE#

I set the height of `div` to 100px and want to show the `label` at the bottom of the `div`.  I use

```
#contain-word-lab {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

However, this doesn't work at all. The `label` still align to the top of the `div`.

Does anyone have any ideas about this? Why `vertical-align` doesn't work here? Thanks!

Comment: vertical-align: "bottom"; why using double quotes `" "`?

Comment: @KheemaPandey a mistake, corrected now

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Why `vertical-align: bottom` is not working alone

Since the height of the parent element is greater than the computed height of the label, Using `vertical-align: bottom` **won't** move that (inline) element to the bottom of the parent.

Because in an inline flow, `vertical-align` determines how the elements are positioned based on their parent's baseline; And using that property on the label won't alter the position of baseline of its parent.

Inline level elements (`inline`, `inline-block`) are sitting in their **[baseline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography))** by default. And if they have different heights, the tallest element will determine where the others whould be placed.

I.e. In an inline flow, the tallest element [will affect/move the baseline of the parent](http://jsbin.com/dewaqa/5/edit):

[image: illustration of baseline]

### Looking for a solution

Hence in cases where [the parent has an explicit `height`](http://jsbin.com/dewaqa/6/edit), if we could have an inline child which has the exact same height as the parent (a full-height child), it would affect the inline flow and move the baseline down:

[image: A full-height element which affects the baseline]

And in order to keep elements (including letters having descenders) within the parent, we should [align them vertically by `vertical-align: bottom;` declaration](http://jsbin.com/dewaqa/8/edit).

[image: applying vertical align property]

> **[10.8 Line height calculations: 'vertical-align' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align)**
>
> **`baseline`**
>   Align the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box. If the box does not have a baseline, align the bottom
>   margin edge with the parent's baseline.
>
> **`bottom`**
>   Align the bottom of the aligned subtree with the bottom of the line box.

## Putting it all together

Therefore you could create a full-height element (Personally I'd rather go with [pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content)) within the parent to align the label at the bottom.

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/fovowu/2/edit)**

```css
#contain-word-div:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;            /* Let it be as height as the parent */
  vertical-align: bottom;  /* Align the element at the bottom   */
}

#contain-word-lab {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;  /* Align the element at the bottom   */
}
```

Comment: thats a nifty little trick, as long as pseudo elements are ok :D

Comment: Thanks! It's very interesting! Do you mean the "pseudo-element" change the baseline of the label? Is there any documents or detailed explainations about this trick?

Comment: @Firegun That's not about the pseudo-element, but about any dummy element which fills the parent vertically while it's in inline level as well. I.e. an inline full-height child. The higher inline element would affect the baseline.

Comment: @downvoter: you really don't have a reason, do you? If so, share with us please.

Comment: @HashemQolami Still not very clear about the baseline/filling rule behind the trick..

Comment: @Firegun Just take a look at **[this demo](http://jsbin.com/dewaqa/2/edit)** When the parent doesn't have an explicit height, the taller inline element affects the baseline of the inline elements. Hence in your particular case that the parent has an explicit height, if we could have a child that has an exact height, it'll affect the baseline and move that to bottom.

Comment: @Firegun I added more details to the answer. Hope it makes things clear.

Answer (score 8):

quick example

http://jsfiddle.net/oa2gmuq3/

if you add

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
```

to the label it likes to keep it at the bottom

Answer (score 3):

set it as position:absolute;

```
#contain-word-lab {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Apply `position:relative` to the parent div and make your label as `position:absolute`.

```
 #contain-word-div {
 height: 100px;
 position:relative;
 }
 #contain-word-lab {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:5px;
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/g9rvbd6h/)

Comment: simple one!! why we need to set relative to parent? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

`vertical-align` tends to work best when the containers are table/table-like elements (eg. `table`, `tr`, `td`, `th`) or inline text elements (eg `span`). However, because `table` elements for layout are not a good idea. We can make other elements function like them using the `display:table;` and `display:table-cell;` css properties.

Try applying the following css:

```
#contain-word-div {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black; /* added just for visualising position */
  display:table;
}
#contain-word-lab {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding-bottom: 5px; /* use padding to give the label more height rather than trying to push the "cell" upwards */
}
```

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/KxGLH8TjaS)

Comment: While true, since the OP is using TW Bootstrap, changing the display type of the column to `table` may cause a trouble.

Comment: possibly, but it could always be contained within a `div` element if that doesnt become a worry. here is an example with other `div`s around it without issue. http://www.bootply.com/gmpFwz4lIn

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` only applies to table cells.  If you want to position an element at the bottom of its parent, you need to give it `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;`.

Comment: `vertical-align only applies to table cells` Not true. It's applicable to inline level and table cells element.

Comment: and also to inline-block elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do following

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/db5srcn9/)**

```
#contain-word-lab {
    vertical-align='bottom';/***Remove This***/
    bottom:2px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: So it'll be positioned with the respect of the initial containing block which is established for `<html>` element. I.e at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The "bottom" won't work anyway :) Try just `bottom`, without ".
Plus your label needs a height too. Now it's auto height is used and this is exactly the font-size. I'd suggest adding a `line-height: 100px;` to your label.