# Vertically align text as middle in span/label irrespective of screen resolution not working

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am able to vertically align text in span(which is inside div) but i need my page to be independent of screen resolution. have used line height feature to curb the my text from going out of the div when I change the resolution..but I see its not vertically aligned as middle in all resolution. what feature in css i should look into?

```
<div>
 <span style="width:49%; height:50%; top:25%; left:0%; line-height:50%;font-size:x-small;font-family:Verdana;font-weight:bold; position:absolute; display:block;">
      Random Text
    </span>
</div>
```

The above span tag is inside a div. Also What should be the recommended value of line-height.Should it be same as height of the span tag?
I saw [this link](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/) for understanding the vertical aligning of single line text.

> >
>   Some other CSS doubts>>
>   1. a textbox inside a div containing single line of text also goes out of the control while changing screen resolution. what could I possibly do to solve this?I am about to control it in a button

Comment: Please post the relative HTML, CSS code you have tried so far.

Comment: Can't help you without a clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove those `position` unless extremely needed and use, `display:table-cell`

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hL9ugLa7/)

```
div  span {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:49%;
    height:50%;
    display:table-cell; /*check this */
    vertical-align:middle; /**aligns where you want it */
    font-size:x-small;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

You might wanna check out this thread too : [Align multiple divs in one line and center text veticaly and horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430203/align-multiple-divs-in-one-line-and-center-text-veticaly-and-horizontally)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. It worked.please see my edit for some more css doubts.

Comment: @gotoVoid : `goes out of the control`..how? can you give a fiddle of it?

Comment: Hey I was wrong @noobEditor.it doesn't go out. everything works. thanks for the instant help

Comment: @gotoVoid : always a pleasure!! :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pratikp2891991/mxpekunq/. THIS IS MY FIDDLE DEMO.. i followed your steps. why is it looking dfferently in 800x600 resolution

Comment: @gotoVoid : because you have given `table-cell` to an `absolute` positioned element....you'll have to remove `position` if you want `vertical-align` to work.....any particular reason why you are making everything `absolute`??

Answer (score 2):

You could position the span element vertically at the middle by using `top: 50%` and adding a negative top margin which is equal to half of the height of the line.

Here you go:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/qaliyu/5/watch?html,output)**

```
span {
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%; left:0;

  font-size: 0.7em; 
  line-height: 100%;  /* 100% of font-size */

  margin-top: -0.35em;
}
```

However if you're not eager to use absolute positioning, you could follow **[this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457954/vertical-align-span-text-inside-inline-block-div/25459423#25459423)**.

**Note:** I've nothing against `table-cell`s, except [the effect `relative` positioning is undefined](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position) for such types of elements. If you don't mind, you could follow [@NoobEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3154233/noobeditor)'s solution as well.

Comment: `independent of screen resolution` - not meeting this mate!!

Comment: OP wants a responsive solution to vertical alignment of text in middle inside `span`!

Comment: @NoobEditor What do you mean? This IS a responsive solution, just try to change the container's height.

Comment: @NoobEditor Actually the previous link was broken accidentally, check the new one please :)

Comment: @NoobEditor Just use Chrome Developer tool :)

Comment: and we restart out history of UN-unanimous answer!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor indeed :)