# Vertical-Align list item to bottom

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I've read through plenty of related articles on this site and others and it seems I'm still missing something pretty basic.

I have a parent div and an unordered list. The div has a set height and I want to list items to be inline-line and on the bottom of the parent div.

Thanks!

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/np2qm6rz/1/

```
<div class="parent">
    <ul>
        <li> Item 1 </li>
        <li> Item 1 </li>
        <li> Item 1 </li>
        <li> Item 1 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
.parent {
    border: 1px solid lime;
    height: 100px;
}
ul {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
li {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is adding a full-height (pseudo-)element to the `.parent` to affect the parent's baseline and move the inline level elements to the bottom of the box, Then use `vertical-align: bottom` declaration in order to keep elements - including letters having descenders - within the parent:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/np2qm6rz/4/)**

```css
.parent:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

ul {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

li { float: left; }
```

You could refer to my answer for further info:

- [How to align a label to the "BOTTOM" of a div in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419552/how-to-align-a-label-to-the-bottom-of-a-div-in-css/25419852#25419852)

Answer (score 1):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/np2qm6rz/2/)

Add `position:relative` to your parent tag and `position:absolute; bottom:0px` to your list, so it sticks to the bottom of the div.

Edit:
Updated jsfiddle link.

Comment: Thanks Kamil,
I tried going that route, but it causes a whole bunch of bugs down the chain at different breakpoints. I'm only going down that route if it's only the way.

Comment: @JasonWagner, what kind of bugs? Can you add to your question the DOM elements that get the bugs?

Comment: Maybe, "bugs" is the wrong term. I have other absolutely positions on this section and it would require serious refactoring across multiple breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`display: table-cell;`

on parent div

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/np2qm6rz/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier solution using your own code...

[Link ->](http://jsfiddle.net/np2qm6rz/9/)

Here is the CSS

```
.parent {
    border: 1px solid lime;
    height: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
ul {
    display: inline-block;
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
li {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <ul>
        <li> Item 1 </li>
        <li> Item 1 </li>
        <li> Item 1 </li>
        <li> Item 1 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```