# How to vertically center a col in a bootstrap 3 container element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

could you tell me how to vcenter a col within a bootstrap3 container? I came up with the solution to define it as a display:table, but the problem is that the col get's an height of 100% then.
Thanks in advance...

```
<div class="container" style="height:100%;">
   <div class="row" style="height:100%;">
      <div class="col-md-6">
       Vertrically center me!
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Edited:**

All I had to do was add another div as innercontainer. Thanks you

```
<div class="container" style="height:100%;">
   <div class="row" style="height:100%;">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="inner-container">
            Vertrically center me!
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at [vertical-align with bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3). Also this could be inspiring: [How to center align vertically the container in bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196587/how-to-center-align-vertically-the-container-in-bootstrap)

Comment: Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/zukife/1/edit