# Bootstrap Glyphicons not showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I´m using bootstrap 3 and I put one Glyphicons side by side with a input text and Glyphicons not showing (but the btn-info show) I'm using: class="input-group" to envolve the glyphicon, input text and submit button.

here is the code:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> 
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button> 
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Meu Site</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Create Account</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span7 text-center col-md-4 col-md-offset-3" style="float: none; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">
                <img src="../../app.images/logo.jpg" />
            </div>
            <form class="span7 text-center col-md-4 col-md-offset-3" style="float: none; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Opt1</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" checked="">Opt2</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Opt3</label>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info input-group-btn">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                    </a>
                    <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Search" />
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="span7 text-center col-md-4 col-md-offset-3" style="float: none; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">
                Slogan
            </div>
            <div class="span7 text-center col-md-4 col-md-offset-3" style="float: none; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">
                <a href="#">Mobile</a>
                <a href="#">Addons</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @teeyo Try testing with Bootply or JSFiddle before asking that. The Icon doesn't show up there, so it won't matter if he has the fonts or not.

Comment: I don't see the problem. Seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/2916/

Comment: @Invent-Animate That's an image link, not a glyphicon. However, I see a problem: http://www.bootply.com/l9xWSGFDWU

Comment: Yes, I put the Glyphicons in another area and works but in this place didn't work

Comment: @Invent-Animate He was talking about a glyphicon not about an image with a relative path.

Comment: @RicardoHenrique are you changing Bootstrap style some way?

Comment: I didn't understood your question @DavidMorenoGarcía

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [Bootstrap glyphicon not showing in Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659094/bootstrap-glyphicon-not-showing-in-form/35660280#35660280)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems to be caused by .input-group-btn. There is a rule to set font-size of this element to 0. Add an style rule with this:

```
div.container a.input-group-btn {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

[Working sample](http://www.bootply.com/HM0Kiijm1T)

Comment: you knows how I can align Vertically e Horizontally the <div class="container">?

Comment: @RicardoHenrique You have a nice article about that here http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

Comment: Take a look to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196587/how-to-center-align-vertically-the-container-in-bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

After reading many threads on this topic, here's the solution I came up that finally fixed my Glyphicon bug:

Find directory **fonts**

```
directory path: node_modules/bootstrap/fonts
```

Copy & paste **fonts** directory into your sourced bootstrap directory from which you've been developing already.

I'm using Grunt as my task manager, therefore in my **Gruntfile.js** I made sure to grunt the following:

```
copy: {
        main: {
            expand: true,
            cwd: "node_modules/",
            src: [

                "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css.map",
                "bootstrap/*.*",
                "bootstrap/**/*.*"
            ],

            "dest": "server/public/vendor/"
        }
    },
```

My tears finally went away afterwards :)

Answer (score 0):

[Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/CBvMIPAHzT)

I'll post this as an alternative to your search bar:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></button>
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</div><!-- /input-group -->
```

Basically, replace this code:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info input-group-btn">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
  </a>
  <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Search" />
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the one above, and add a Javascript handler to the button if you want to navigate somewhere (notice it's not an `<a>` tag anymore).

Hope this helps!

**Note**

The issue (I think) arises from using `input-group-btn` on an `<a>` tag that's styled as a button. In the Bootstrap examples, the `input-group-btn` is a span with a `<button>` tag inside it. You could also try putting the `<span class="input-group-btn">` around your `<a>` tag and seeing if that makes a difference.