# Alignment using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use AngularJs, Bootstrap, NodeWebkit.

I'm trying to create my pages' header like this :
[image]
So here is my code :

```
<div class="row">
<img class="col-md-offset-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 img-rounded image-module-pd " src="{{titreImage}}"></img>
<h3 class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 text-left titre-module">{{ titreLocalization | translate }}</h3>

<div class="input-group text-right">
    <span id="basic-addon1" class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search" ></span>
    <input class="form-control"  ng-model="recherche_texte" Name="recherche_input" placeholder="{{ 'RECHERCHE_TITRE' | translate }}" type="text" style="width:250px;"/>
</div>

</div>
```

This is what I get :
[image]

There are a few issues : My glyphicon is not fully vertically alignated with the input, why ? I've just pasted the example from bootstrap's documentation.
My input + glyphicon are not on the right
My input + glyphicon are not vertically alignated with my title.

I hope my images are big enough so you can understand my problems.

Thank you

Comment: Try [Bootlint-ing](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint) your page next time. It would have caught several of these errors.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I use it with nodewekit ? I can't really load my pages without nodewekbit because I use angularJs which needs a server (or something else) to load directives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are minor mistakes against important [Bootstrap 3 rules](http://getbootstrap.com/css/):

First:

> Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows

Second:

> If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line.

Third:

> Icon classes cannot be directly combined with other components. They should not be used along with other classes on the same element. Instead, add a nested `<span>` and apply the icon classes to the `<span>`

So, place your image, title and search components into separate `div` with `col` classes and use `offset` where needed, but be sure that your column count doesn't add up over 12, otherwise these contents will wrap onto the next line.

This following is a working example, available at [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/eAJMfXMPKJ) to play around with the code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-1">
    <img class="img-rounded image-module-pd" src="http://placehold.it/100x60">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <h3 class="text-left titre-module">Title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-2">
    <div class="input-group text-right">
      <span id="basic-addon1" class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      </span>
      <input class="form-control" ng-model="recherche_texte" name="recherche_input" placeholder="Search" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that you may omit `col-sm`, `col-md` and `col-lg` classes if a `col-xs` class is present and you don't need other breakpoints on larger screen widths:

> Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, e.g. applying any .col-md-* class to an element will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a .col-lg-* class is not present.

To solve your problem to vertically align the search component read on this other posts that cover this issue:

[vertical-align with bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20547819/3246440)

[How to center align vertically the container in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22196587/3246440)

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying now to align vertically. Also, do I need to add <div class="col-xs-12"> if I have only one div on a page ?

Comment: No. Use any number of columns within a row. The sum of columns depends on your needs. Bootstrap has a default 12 column grid layout. Any number over 12 will wrap to the next line. If you want to fill one row with one div then use `col-xs-12`.