# Center link vertically in a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

There is an "place order" link on the web page, which I want to center both horizontally and vertically. I managed to center it horizontally, but not vertically. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap. This is what it looks like now and the red arrow shows where I'd like to put it:

[image]

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h2 class="specs text-center">specs</h2>
        <p class="text-center"> LENGTH - 1760mm<br />
          TIP WIDTH - 136mm<br />
          WAIST WIDTH - 112mm<br />
          TAIL WIDTH - 126mm<br />
          TIP LENGTH - 300mm<br />
          TAIL LENGTH - 200mm<br />
          CAMBER - 4MM<br />
          TURN RADIUS - 23mtrs<br />
        </p>
      </div>
      <!--end col-md-8-->
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <h2 class="text-center order"><a href="#">place order</a></h2>
      </div>
      <!--end col-md-4--> 
    </div>
    <!--end row--> 
  </div>
  <!--end container-->
```

The CSS:

```
#products .order
{
    background-color: #392e2e;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#products .order a
{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h2.order
{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And [here's](http://skiest.ragne.me/) a link to the project as well, scroll to the very bottom of the page.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry to close it ... realized later that you are using twitter bootstrap but still there should be some question explaining this

Comment: try `vertical-align:30%;` or something like that.

Comment: look at this question, it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196587/how-to-center-align-vertically-the-container-in-bootstrap

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3

Comment: @www139, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Morpheus, I stumbled upon this thread, but that doesn't fix my problem unfortunately. And I've also googled and struggled with this for a few hours now. I'm lost. :)

Comment: sorry I meant `vertical-align:-30%;`

Comment: @bijoume is it because you have white space between vertically aligned divs?

Comment: @bijoume works like a charm -> http://jsfiddle.net/vm087c99/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution. Add this CSS to your stylesheet:

```
.row-same-height {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.col-md-height {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    float: none !important;
}
```

Now, here's your html with the new divs applied.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="row-same-height">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <h2 class="specs text-center">specs</h2>
          <p class="text-center"> LENGTH - 1760mm<br />
            TIP WIDTH - 136mm<br />
            WAIST WIDTH - 112mm<br />
            TAIL WIDTH - 126mm<br />
            TIP LENGTH - 300mm<br />
            TAIL LENGTH - 200mm<br />
            CAMBER - 4MM<br />
            TURN RADIUS - 23mtrs<br />
          </p>
        </div>
        <!--end col-md-8-->
        <div class="col-md-height col-md-4 text-center">
          <h2 class="text-center order"><a href="#">place order</a></h2>
        </div>
        <!--end col-md-4--> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end row--> 
  </div>
  <!--end container-->
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help? http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

```
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Have in mind so it works on IE10+, and add a specific class to this row!

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this, I had update code.

```css
#products .order
{
    background-color: #392e2e;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.container{
    .row{
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
}
    .col-md-8,.col-md-4{
        display: table-cell;
    width: 60%;
    float: none !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
.col-md-4{width: 40%;}
}

#products .order a
{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h2.order
{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h2 class="specs text-center">specs</h2>
        <p class="text-center"> LENGTH - 1760mm<br />
          TIP WIDTH - 136mm<br />
          WAIST WIDTH - 112mm<br />
          TAIL WIDTH - 126mm<br />
          TIP LENGTH - 300mm<br />
          TAIL LENGTH - 200mm<br />
          CAMBER - 4MM<br />
          TURN RADIUS - 23mtrs<br />
        </p>
      </div>
      <!--end col-md-8-->
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <h2 class="text-center order"><a href="#">place order</a></h2>
      </div>
      <!--end col-md-4--> 
    </div>
    <!--end row--> 
  </div>
  <!--end container-->
```