# How can I align li elements in ul vertically centered?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a `ul` which is has the elements laid out horizontally in a menu format. I want to make the `li`'s be vertically aligned in the space the `ul` occupies, however I'm struggling to get it to work.

Does anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong?

**CSS**

```
a { 
    color:#d82727; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    font-weight:normal; 
}
a:link { 
    color:#d82727; 
}
a:visited { 
    color:#d82727; 
}
a:focus { 
    color:#d82727; 
}
a:hover { 
    color:#d82727; 
    font-weight:bold; 
}


#menu_bar {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height:40px;
    border-bottom:2px #eeeeee solid;
    padding-left:20%;
    padding-right:20%;
}
#menu_bar ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
}
#menu_bar ul li {
    display: inline;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
}
#menu_bar ul li a:hover {
    color:#d82727;
    font-weight:bold;
}


.active { 
    color:#d82727; 
    border-bottom:2px #d82727 solid; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu_bar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#/foo" class="active">Foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/bar">Bar</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And a fiddle of my current Code [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ehduhayh/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are multiple ways to achieve vertical alignment. However, since the list items are being `display`ed as `inline` in this case, you could that by adding a full-height inline element having `vertical-align` of `middle` to the `<ul>` as follows:

```css
#menu_bar ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
```

This method is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196587/how-to-center-align-vertically-the-container-in-bootstrap/22196760#22196760) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474#18516474). Here is an online example:

```css
a { 
    color:#d82727; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    font-weight:normal; 
}
a:link { 
    color:#d82727; 
}
a:visited { 
    color:#d82727; 
}
a:focus { 
    color:#d82727; 
}
a:hover { 
    color:#d82727; 
    font-weight:bold; 
}

#menu_bar {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height:40px;
    border-bottom:2px #eeeeee solid;
    padding-left:20%;
    padding-right:20%;
}

#menu_bar ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
}

#menu_bar ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

#menu_bar ul li {
    display: inline;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
}
#menu_bar ul li a:hover {
    color:#d82727;
    font-weight:bold;
}


.active { 
    color:#d82727; 
    border-bottom:2px #d82727 solid; 
}
```

```html
<div id="menu_bar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#/foo" class="active">Foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/bar">Bar</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```