# Vertical and horizontal centering of content in a responsive bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I am working in a bootstrap project where i need some text to be centered vertically with another row. Obviously the two rows are not the same size hence the content size. Is there a way to solve this without escalating to flexbox or is this the way to go? Also i would like to maintain the responsiveness.

Fiddle: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPwxXa

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
        <img src="http://rack.2.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDE1LzA5LzEzLzNjL2dvb2dsZXRodW1iLmIyNGE0LmpwZwpwCXRodW1iCTk1MHg1MzQjCmUJanBn/63126c72/af4/google-thumb.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
      <p>This is some text some text some more text</p>
      <p>This is some text some text some more text</p>
      <p>This is some text some text some more text</p>
      <p>This is some text some text some more text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: [Have you seen this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196587/how-to-center-align-vertically-the-container-in-bootstrap)

Comment: What if flexbox is the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `Flexbox` and `media queries`.

As for flexbox you can just use `display: flex` and `align-items: center` on parent element and that will be `row` in this case.

Now you just need to adjust `min-width` in media queries to be same as **bootstrap breakpoints** So for example if you are using `col-sm-6` bootstrap class, then **768px** is break point and you will use `@media(min-width: 768px) { }` in your media queries.

- For `col-sm-` you can use `@media(min-width: 768px)` [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/520/)
- For `col-md-` you can use `@media(min-width: 992px)` [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/522/)
- For `col-lg-` you can use `@media(min-width: 1200px)` [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/524/)

```css
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row flex">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <img src="http://rack.2.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDE1LzA5LzEzLzNjL2dvb2dsZXRodW1iLmIyNGE0LmpwZwpwCXRodW1iCTk1MHg1MzQjCmUJanBn/63126c72/af4/google-thumb.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
      <p>This is some text some text some more text</p>
      <p>This is some text some text some more text</p>
      <p>This is some text some text some more text</p>
      <p>This is some text some text some more text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead of `Flexbox` you can also get vertical-align with **CSS Tables** and again you have to adjust your queries with bootstrap breakpoints same as for flexbox. With tables you have to remove **float** from columns with `float: none` to get vertical-align.

```css
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .row.display_table {
    display: table;
  }
  
  .col-sm-6.left_cell, .col-sm-6.right_cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
  }
  
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row display_table">
    <div class="col-sm-6 left_cell">
      <img src="http://rack.2.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDE1LzA5LzEzLzNjL2dvb2dsZXRodW1iLmIyNGE0LmpwZwpwCXRodW1iCTk1MHg1MzQjCmUJanBn/63126c72/af4/google-thumb.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 right_cell text-center">
      <p>This is some text some text some more text</p>
      <p>This is some text some text some more text</p>
      <p>This is some text some text some more text</p>
      <p>This is some text some text some more text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to be too simple, but you are wondering if `flexbox` is the way to go. Actually, at this time, it is.

The reason behind the text container is that you don't need to use `text-align:center;` to center your text if you don't want to, but it is still horizontal centered.

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .vcenter {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .text {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row vcenter">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 ">
        <img src="http://rack.2.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDE1LzA5LzEzLzNjL2dvb2dsZXRodW1iLmIyNGE0LmpwZwpwCXRodW1iCTk1MHg1MzQjCmUJanBn/63126c72/af4/google-thumb.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="text">
        <p>This is some text some te xt some more text</p>
        <p>This is some text some text some more text</p>
        <p>This is some text some text some more text</p>
        <p>This is some text some text some more text</p>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting solution! Unfortunately `col-xs-12` is never triggered for some reason?

Comment: My bad, `flebox` should only be used till the breakpoint of `col-xs-12`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a div with relative position like:

```
<div style='position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(50%); height:100%;'>
```

To encapsulate all the `<p>` tags and align middle. There are a lot of methods like (http://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/):

```
#parent {display: table;}

#child {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

but with inline elements didn't work quite well. Note I change the `col-lg-6` to `col-sm-6`, because in codepen you could see the 2 columns.

Extracted from here: https://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-center

Here a working codepen: http://codepen.io/jpaulet/pen/bpRvyd?editors=1100

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! But the codepen does not seem to illustrate the result i am looking for.

Comment: Why not? It works exactly as the image you posted... Note the: "I changed the col-lg-6 to col-sm-6, because in codepen you could see the 2 columns".

Comment: I see this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5bhn8pytr5qve28/codepen.png?dl=0 .. but let me see it again

Comment: The key problem is that the first column with the image is not the same height as the second one, therefor you cannot use this solution.