# Bootstrap: Center a container-fluid vertically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to centre a container-fluid in it's parent container (body tag).
Here is an example of my webpage : [image]

The container in question is the one I've coloured in black to identify better.
There are two other divs:

```
 - The top one which is a (nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top")
 - The bottom one which is a (nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom")
```

The question is: how can I centre my container-fluid (in black) to always be in the middle of my page ? The content of this container will change dynamically and I cant it to always stay in the middle (same margin top and bottom)

Thanks guys.

EDIT : as requested, HTML and CSS :

HTML :

```
<body ng-controller="LanguageController as language">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#language" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="language">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> {{ language.lblAppName }}</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="language">
    <div class="container vertical-center">
      <label> {{ language.lblSelectLanguage }} </label>
      <select ng-options="item for item in language.languages" ng-model="language.selectedLanguage" ng-change="language.changeLanguage()"></select>
      <button ng-click="language.editLanguage()">{{ language.lblEditLanguage }}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
 </nav>


 <div id="corpus" class="container-fluid" ng-view="">
 </div>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#route" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="route">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-brand"> {{ language.lblFooter }} </div>
  </div>
  <div id="route" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#"> {{ language.lblMainPage }} </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">{{ language.lblFirstPage }}</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">{{ language.lblSecondPage }}</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">{{ language.lblThirdPage }}</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS :

```
 body {
padding-top: 70px;
/* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-    top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
 }

.container {
 display: table;
}

.vertical-center {
 display: table-cell;
 padding-top: 1%;
 padding-left: 5%;
}

.vertical-center label.ng-binding{
color:grey;
}


div#corpus.container-fluid.ng-scope {
background-color:default;
}

div#mainDiv a.ng-binding {
color: black;
text-decoration: underline;
}

.top-buffer { 
margin-top:2%; 
}
```

Comment: provide html and css for the elements

Comment: You might find an Angular directive out there that can do this. Could the content ever be larger than the visible screen? If so, think about changing your layout when this happens.

Comment: @Dejan.S Done, thanks

Comment: @spongessuck I want to center it vertically, So that the padding is the same at the top and the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, this question has been [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196587/how-to-center-align-vertically-the-container-in-bootstrap).

```
.vertical-center {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh; 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

<div class="container-fluid vertical-center">
    Vertically centered in body.....
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/oX2f8eBxFv

Comment: Thanks ! I saw this link before but that didn't work for me before. That gave me weird layout and I thought that was not was I was looking for. Turns out I had a conflict with another div with a custom class that messed everything up.