# How to vertically center row in container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

By default the row aligns to the top.

I tried to put margin-top: auto; and margin-bottom: auto; but doesn't work.
Also vertical-align: middle; also does not work.

Is there an easy fix to this?

Thanks

```css
.container {
background-color:black;
height: 100px;
}

.row {
background-color:#fff;
height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: I have been looking through other solutions, but they are not specific about rows in bootstrap.

Answer (score 17):

You can use **`flexbox`** for this:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Use this in the parent of the element you want to center vertically! Works like a charm!

Comment: nice answer! :)

Answer (score 3):

Basically, this [question is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196587/how-to-center-align-vertically-the-container-in-bootstrap). There are various centering methods for Bootstrap explained in that question. This will work specifically for your scenario with the `row` inside the `container`. Here are 2 different methods..

```
// method 1 flexbox
.container-flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

// method 2 translatey
.v-center {
    position: relative;
    transform: translatey(-50%);
    top: 50%;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/b6wTQTzoe1

Answer (score 0):

Set width and height for row and

```
.row {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: That is for horizontal alignment, not vertical

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="inner">
    <p>
      Text
    </p>
</div>

.inner {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background: orange;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

The "Text" should be vertically aligned.
Display table-cell works with vertical-align.
I think it should be possible to do it with inline-elements too.