# background image doesn't always center as it should

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a website for my final project and right now working on final touches.
I wrote it using bootstrap and used the grid : .col-sm
Now I am making sure it looks the same at all screen resolution.

I entered the site via my LG4 and this was the view:
[image]

but when view site on my PC using chrome mobile resolution it appears more similar to the way I want:
[image]

This is the css:

```
#index-wrap{
    background: url('pic/start.jpg') ;

    margin-bottom: 0;
    min-height: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    /*now:*/
     background-attachment: fixed;
}

.jumbotron {
    background-color: transparent; 
    color: #0E76BD; 
    text-align: center;
    height: 100vh;

}
```

And these are the dives hierarchy:

```
<div id="index-wrap">
    <div class="jumbotron">

-----Site Content ------

    </div>
</div>
```

How I fix this?

Comment: did you try remove  background-attachment: fixed;?

Comment: it did not do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end , I cropped the Image and displayed different images in each device:

@

```
media(max-width:767px){

   #index-wrap{
      background: url('pic/start2.jpg') ;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      min-height: 50%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center center;
      webkit-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
   }

    .vertical-center > .container {
       max-width: 90%;
       min-height: 80%;
       display: inline-block;
       vertical-align: middle;  /* vertical alignment of the inline element */                       
       font: 16px/1 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
}
```

And in default view:

```
   #index-wrap{
      background: url('pic/start.jpg') ;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      min-height: 50%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center center;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
   }

   .jumbotron {
      background-color: transparent; 
      color: #0E76BD; 
       text-align: center;
       height: 100vh;
   }

    .vertical-center {
        width:100%;
        min-height: 80%;
        text-align: center; 
        font: 0/0 a;         
    }

    .vertical-center:before { 
        content: " ";
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;    /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
        height: 100%;
    }

    .vertical-center > .container {
        max-width: 100%;
        min-height: 75%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;  
        font: 16px/1 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
```

And this is the html hierarchy:

```
<div id="index-wrap" >
   <div class="jumbotron vertical-center" >
      <div class="container">
.....
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Its not very elegant, but it does the trick.
I took the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22196760/3154068) and changed the URL and container max width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Use background-size:cover as a fallback for

```
background-size: 100vw auto;
```

It will scale the background width to the width of the viewport, so the image doesn't clip horizontally on any device that supports viewport units (93% of devices).