# Best way to center div in responsive div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying for several hours to both vertically and horizontally center a div with no specific width or height in a parent div that has a `max-width` and `max-height` but will be responsive. I've looked at both CSS and JS/jQuery options with nothing working properly.

[**As you can see**](http://cl.ly/ULBz), it's a thumbnail preview for a video. When in a `normal` state, it just shows the thumbnail with a play icon above it. In a `hover` state, it changes the play button to an orange one, displays the title, and has a black transparent overlay above the thumbnail.

Now, this would be easy to do with CSS if the site wasn't responsive. But, as the browser width decreases, the thumbnail sizes decrease.

Here's the HTML I'm using:

```
<article class="movie"><a href="#">

    <div class="movie-overlay">

        <div class="movie-play"></div>

        <h2 class="movie-title">Title Goes Here</h2>

    </div> <!-- end .movie-overlay -->

    <div class="movie-thumb"><img src="thumbs/thumb.jpg"/></div>

</a></article> <!-- end #post- -->
```

And here's my CSS:

```
.movie-archive .movie {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 480px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}

.movie-archive .movie .movie-overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}

.movie-archive .movie:hover .movie-overlay {background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);}

.movie-archive .movie .movie-play {
    background: url("images/play-icon@2x.png") no-repeat center 0;
    background-size: 94px 190px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 95px;
}

.movie-archive .movie:hover .movie-play {background-position-y: -95px;}

.movie-archive .movie .movie-title {
    font-size: 17px;
    letter-spacing: -0.01em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: none;
    padding: 10px 50px 0;
}

.movie-archive #latest-top.movie:hover .movie-title, .movie:hover .movie-title {display: block;}

.movie-archive .movie .movie-thumb img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

I've tried various things from adding another div and using the `display: table` trick to adding padding as a percentage, and using JS. Nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any suggestions? I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Not that it really matters, but I am using WordPress for this site.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474#18516474

Comment: And this may be of interest: http://www.tipue.com/blog/center-a-div/

Comment: @HashemQolami thanks for the article. Unfortunately I could not get it to work.

Comment: @Whymarrh the problem is I don't know the width/height of the divs.

Answer (score 1):

The container and the elemented you want centered should have properties like this:

```
.movie-archive .movie {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 480px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}

.movie-archive .movie .movie-overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50%; //half of width
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50%; //half of height
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center; //only if you want the text to be centered
}
```

Source: http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/

Comment: [This](http://cl.ly/UL9N) is what happens when I replace my code with yours. And idea why?

Comment: sorry, stupid typo. The margins should have been `-50%`

Comment: That's not really working either. [Here's what it looks like](http://cl.ly/UOKI). Note, I disabled `overflow: hidden` temporarily so you can see what it does. It seems when I edit the code to `top: 89%` it works. Any idea why?

Comment: I hove no clue why that works. But it seems like You are centering the wrong thing at the moment. You should try centering the play button in the overlay instead of the overlay over the movie. Search for "With fluid width" in the article I linked and you can probably figure it out by yourself

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {w = $(window).width();
h = $(window).height();
jQuery.each($('.centerony'), function(i, val) {
lung = $(val).css('height');
a = (h * 0.5) - ((parseInt(lung)) * 0.5);
$(val).css('position', 'absolute');
$(val).css('top', a + 'px')
});
jQuery.each($('.centeronx'), function(i, val) {
larg = $(val).css('width');
a = (w * 0.5) - ((parseInt(larg)) * 0.5);
$(val).css('position', 'absolute');
$(val).css('left', a + 'px')
});

$(window).resize(function() {
k = $(window).width();
z = $(window).height();
jQuery.each($('.centeronx'), function(i, val) {
larg = $(val).css('width'); 
a = (k * 0.5) - ((parseInt(larg)) * 0.5);
$(val).css('left', a + 'px')
})
jQuery.each($('.centerony'), function(i, val) {
lung = $(val).css('height');
a = (z * 0.5) - ((parseInt(lung)) * 0.5);
$(val).css('position', 'absolute');
$(val).css('top', a + 'px')
});
});
});
```

Add to the element you want to center class 'centerony' and class 'centeronx', and set parent's div (the one which has max-width and max-height with position:relative. It should work.

```
<div id="outdiv" class="outside" style="position:relative">

<div class="in_div centerony centeronx">I am centered!</div>

</div>
```

You have to use include jQuery to use it. :)

PAY ATTENTION -------
the code i wrote works according to window's size, and not parent's div size. 
If you want to adapt to your case, change the values of vars w,h,k,z, making their value in relation with parent's div size instead of window size. for example `w = $('#outdiv').width()` instead of `w = $(window).width();`

Comment: For some reason the value for `top` and `left` are too much. [See this image](http://cl.ly/UM6P). Thanks!

Comment: have you changed the vars w,h,k,z ? @Connor

Comment: No I didn't even though you wrote "PAY ATTENTION". Whoops! :) I just changed it from `window` to `'.movie'` and no luck. Any idea why?

Comment: if you've changed w,h,k,z and you set your parent's div position to relative, it should work. try to get parent's div using an id instead of a class, cause if you use this class more than once it could makes problem.

Comment: It needs to be a class because the element appears more than once.

Comment: you have to select with this the div that contains your divs you have to center, not the divs you have to center!! @Connor

Comment: Yes, I know. I am trying to select `.movie` which is the parent of `.movie-overlay` (the div that will be centered).