# How to center image in div (height - % of screen)

Tags: css, html, height, percentage

My website has a header and it takes 20% of screen. I want an image (which is 90% of header height) right in the center of the header. I had no problems to center the image horizontally, but I can't center it vertically. Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylingpercent.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <div class="logoheader" >
            <img class="mainlogo" src="logo.png" alt="logo">
        </div>

    </header>



</body>

</html>
```

---

```
body {
    margin:0px;
}


.logoheader{
    height: 20vh;
    background:rgb(1,1,1);
    margin:0px;
    text-align: center;
}


.mainlogo { 
    max-height:90%;
}
```

Comment: Is the height of the image static?

Comment: no, it depends on header height

Comment: for vertical alignment you can refer [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474#18516474). Here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/munak/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
line-height: 20vh;
```

to `.logoheader`. [DEMONstration](http://jsfiddle.net/s96Dx/).