# Vertically align image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have searched here but can't seem to find a solution for my problem due to the dynamic nature of the divs.

For my site I want a banner image that will scale down as a cheap kinda responsiveness. I have that part down pat, I just cannot get my image to center vertically. I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2Vta/) and the code is below.

HTML

```
<div class="banner col-lg-12">
    <img src="http://laurentvandessel.be/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/placeholder.png" /> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.banner {
    margin-top: 51px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align: center;
    height:300px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.banner img {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: -200%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Also, if you have a better way of doing what I'm already doing that would be appreciated as well.

Thanks heaps guys.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474#18516474

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little tricky, because sometimes the image is taller than the container. You could do it like this, though (see the last three lines):

```
.banner img {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -200%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

If that suits, you might as well use this method for horizontal centering too:

```
.banner img {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your last one solution. Worked perfectly with no modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need dynamical div Height for img with dynamical height!
set your css

```
.banner{height:auto; ...}
```

if you need a center vertically and also Horizontally div for TEXT and also images you can look on my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrafiee91/Czvm9/1/) test.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/r2Vta/3/)**</kbd>

css

```
.banner {
    margin-top: 51px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    /*overflow:hidden;
    text-align: center;*/
    height:300px;
    /*display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;*/
    background: url(http://laurentvandessel.be/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/placeholder.png) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
/*.banner img {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: -200%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}*/
```

html

```
<div class="banner col-lg-12">
    <!--<img src="http://laurentvandessel.be/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/placeholder.png" />-->
</div>
```