# How to center the image both horizontally and vertically in span tag?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have used `img` tag inside `span` tag. I have made the span tag's display as inline-block and given it a background color. How can I center the image inside the span tag ?

```
<span class='plus' id='plus_block_1'> <img src='images/plus.png' /> </span>
```

CSS:

```
.plus {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Horizontally or vertically? That's the question.

Comment: Then you might want to consider this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474#18516474

Comment: Will you have more content inside this span, that you really need the image to align? Or are you just trying to border up the image with the span?? Because it seems like a simple `padding` solution...

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by giving the `.plus` a line-height that matches the height of the element. Then set the `img` to `vertical-align: middle`.

See example (twice the height to make it clear): http://jsfiddle.net/1om0emoe/

Comment: Also checkout this complete guide for Centering in CSS by Chris Coyier:
http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/