# Scale image maintaining aspect ratio, then center vertically and horizontally inside fluid height and width DIV

Tags: css, image, centering, fluid-layout

OK, this is a bit of a mouthful and very super specific. I will try my best to explain!

The goal is to maintain aspect ratio while scaling an image and keeping it vertically and horizontally centred inside a DIV that is defined only by percentages. The image needs to maintain best fit, so if max width is required then it's used and vice versa.

**Use *Firefox version 33 (or a few earlier versions)* to view this js fiddle to see it working properly:**

http://jsfiddle.net/3vr9v2fL/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="imageviewer" >

<div class="dummy"></div>
<div class="img-container centerer" id="imagevieweroriginal">
<img class="centered" src="http://chrisnuzzaco.com/couch/uploads/image/gallery/smiling_woman_wearing_drivers_cap.jpg"  alt="Doctor Concentrating on Work"></img>
</div> 

</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#imagewrapper{
position:absolute;
width:69%;
height:100%;
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
background-color:gray;
}


#imageviewer{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}





.responsive-container {

position: relative;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid black;
}


.dummy {
padding-top: 100%; /* forces 1:1 aspect ratio */
}

.img-container {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}

.centerer {
text-align:center; /* Align center inline elements */
font: 0/0 a;       /* Hide the characters like spaces */
}

.centerer:before {
content: ' ';
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 100%;
}

.centered {

vertical-align: middle;
display: inline-block;
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

**The Problem:**

I originally found my code here on stackoverflow and made a simple mod adding max-height/width to the .centered class. At the time, this worked in all major browsers. The only exception being Opera.

[Vertically align an image inside a div with responsive height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height)

There is a big problem however: the latest version of Chrome (Version 38.0.2125.111) no longer works with this code and my users prefer chrome to other browsers by a large margin.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Is this a bug with Chrome? I'm open to javascript suggestions to make this work again.

Answer (score 7):

I came up with this: [JSFiddle - centered image keeps aspect ratio in resizable fluid container](https://jsfiddle.net/paull78/g33wLvhr/)

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.image {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <img class='image' src='http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample1_l.jpg'>
</div>
```

The image stays centered both horizontally and vertically. If the window is scaled down the image shrinks respecting original aspect ratio.

I didn't test it on all browsers though.

Comment: I used the same solution. But on a large screen, the image does not take the full width/height of the container though. Would be great if you could revise your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [CSS object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property:

You may need a [polyfill](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit) for older browsers, though.

[View browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit) for object-fit.