# Vertically center content in a box with a fixed aspect ratio using pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Using HTML/CSS, I'm trying to create the following:

- a fluid-size box with a fixed aspect ratio (16:9)
- a 50% black overlay inside the box
- vertically centered arbitrary content on top of the overlay

I combined a couple of techniques that I found:

- vertical centering: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/
- maintaining aspect ratio: http://martinbean.co.uk/blog/2013/09/12/maintaining-aspect-ratio-in-css/

to arrive at something pretty close to the target:

http://codepen.io/troywarr/pen/zxNdKP?editors=110

That looks great in a 1280px wide viewport, but if you stretch the browser narrower or wider, you'll see that the `.overlay` maintains a fixed height while the `.container` resizes fluidly while still maintaining a 16:9 aspect ratio.

If I could set the value of line 20 to `100%` and thus have `.overlay` expand to the visual height of `.container`, I'd be golden. It's understandable why that doesn't work (`.container` has an actual height of `0`), but I'm stumped as to what to try next.

Please keep in mind that I may be going about this all wrong, and there may be a completely different approach that works better. Ultimately, all that's important to me is:

- cross-browser support back to IE10
- HTML/CSS only (as I could just add some JS to what I have now and get it to work well enough)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there are [couple of ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height) to achieve vertical alignment, however I'm not going to change the whole thing.

You just need to position the `.overlay` element `absolute`ly and expand its dimensions by giving a `width` and `height` of `100%` to it, so that it can fill the entire space of its parent, the `.container`:

**[Example Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BypdJo?editors=110)**

```css
.container {
  /* other declarations... */
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; /* arbitrary */
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Also using `vw` [viewport percentage length](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) could be useful in order for `font-size` property to change with the respect to the viewport size.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #59488b;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 40%;
}

.container {
  background-image: url(http://lorempicsum.com/up/1080/1080/4);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; /* arbitrary */
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.content {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 6vw;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 3vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>This is some text!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Hashem! That's a step in the right direction - looks like the `.overlay` now matches the height of the `.container`. What can I do about vertically centering the content inside, though? In Chrome, at least, it's squished against the top of the box ([screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s223/sh/98ac6017-da88-409b-b9f4-c33b968b1909/ff8030fc4ca97a9f3c427badff5161f7)).