# Align image horizontally and vertically in a scrollable div

Tags: html, css

A have an image and want to be able to zoom it in/out in a scrollable area with fixed size. This is easy, but if the image is smaller than the scrollable area, it should be centered both vertically and horizontally. I can't find a solution how to align it in the middle vertically. Popular solutions like [Vertically align an image inside a div with responsive height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height?rq=1) or [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers) do not work because of the scrollable area.

http://jsfiddle.net/smvyadnv/9/

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner small">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/500/300/nature/"></img>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner large">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/500/300/nature/"></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
.outer {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    overflow: scroll;
    text-align: center;
}
.inner {
    display: inline-block;
}
.inner.small {
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
}
.inner.large {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to center the image, you should instead center the `.inner` element.

You can achieve this using the following vertical / horizontal centering technique (taken from [CSS Tricks - Centering in CSS: A Complete Guide](http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)):

```css
.outer {
    ...
    position: relative;
    ...
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

So your code would look as follows:

```css
img {
    width: 100%;
}
.outer {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: relative;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.inner.small {
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
}
.inner.large {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner small">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/500/300/nature/"></img>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner large">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/500/300/nature/"></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. It works ok in Chrome and FF, but in IE 11, the scroll area behaves strangely.

Answer (score -1):

I just gave your `inner small` image an id called `cent`(center)
and gave it the below css to make it look like it is in the center.

```
#cent{
   padding-top:50px;
}
```

Updated fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/smvyadnv/5/

*Let me know if you are looking for something else*

Comment: Thanks, but the zoom can be dynamic (+/- buttons), so the absolute value of padding will not help.