# How to keep <div> with a Background image have dynamic height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to mimic the following behavior of the div with a background Image.

The page has 3 div on top of one another. They have a maximum width of 600px.
When opened on a smaller screen the width adjusts to the the screen, and the height should adjust too, keeping the aspect ratio of the image which is always 10/7

I tried playing with the background-size style attribute, but that doesn't change the height of the div, so the picture ends up being clipped. I can't afford to clip the image.

Please advise

one
[image]

two
[image]

three
[image]

Comment: Can you post a JS fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, actually it depends on your real markup but this could be a starting point:

The key point is that a percentage value on [top/bottom `padding`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-padding) is relative to the `width` of the box's containing block.

Also, using [`background-size: contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) resizes the background image with aspect ratio. It's worth noting that this feature is supported in IE9+.

For further reading on responsive containers, you could refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474#18516474).

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/ruduha/1/edit?html,css,output)**.

```css
.box {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/300) 50% 50% / contain no-repeat;
  
  width: 80%; /* or whatever else */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.box > span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  padding: 5% 0;
}

.box > span:before,
.box > span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  padding: 2% 0;
}

.box > span:before {
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 90, 79);
}

.box > span:after {
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgb(159, 31, 56);
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis dolores doloremque id quia esse! Doloribus voluptate nihil quam natus, similique, vero amet nesciunt excepturi. Optio dicta quas, dolores facere voluptatem.
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your div only serves to show this image, you can do it simply with this css "trick"

```css
div{
  background: url(http://gogoodscout.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Do-YOu-Feel-Good.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 49%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Notice how if you adjust the padding to reflect the aspect ratio, the div will always have the aspect ratio of the image.

Answer (score 1):

This trick could help you:

```css
#container{
  
background-image:url("http://cdn4.colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/02/Olympic-logo.png"); 
  background-size:cover;
  }

#ghostImg{
  width:100%;
  visibility:hidden;
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://cdn4.colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/02/Olympic-logo.png" id="ghostImg"/>
  </div>
```

Comment: Works :) Thank you David! Really appreciate it.