# centering contents of a div vertically without using height 100%

Tags: html, css

hey guys i am trying to center contents of 2 divs vertically , basically the structure that i have is this :

```
<div>
    <div class="left">
            <span>
             ONCE YOU <br>  
             PICK US, <br>
             YOU WILL <br>
             NEVER <br>
             WANT TO <br>
             GO <br>
             ANYWHERE <br>
             ELSE <br>
            </span>                 
    </div>
    <div class="right">
            <span>Abouts us</span>
            <button class="about-btn"><a href="#">Know More</a></button> 
    </div>
</div>
```

and the technique i am using is the following , which i picked up from solution from a stackoverflow example :

```
                   span:after {
                        content:'';
                        height: 100%;
                        display: inline-block;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                    }
                    span {
                        display:inline-block;
                        vertical-align:middle;
                        font-weight: 700;
                        letter-spacing: -3px;
                        height: 100%;
                    }
```

the problem with this solution is that the  is not the only content in the div and so its not viable for me to give the span `height:100%` as if i have to another element that comes after the span and since the span has a height of 100% in element is pushed outside the main container .

fiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/9ncy4y9u/)

Also another problem is the contents of the `<div class="left">` are not vertically centered with this technique .

i am also trying the display:table solution but that seems to be messing up the layout .

can somebody please help me out with this.

**EDIT::** i was trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474#18516474) solution , by hashem .

thank you .

Alex-Z.

Comment: They are already centered. What exactly do you need?

Comment: @Alexey , the content of `<div class="left">` are not centered .. but more importantly since i have given the span a height of 100% do u see how the button know more is pushed out of the container ?

Comment: I'd suggest flex layout.

Comment: @Leo , still need to start learning that ;) but as of now , i'll leave that option ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it could be done with a table layout :

http://jsfiddle.net/xe6n14xq/

Identifying the parent a making it a table :

```
#wrap {
display: table;
width: 100%; // displaying as table makes the content shrink-wrap
}
```

Then the children can become vertically aligned table-cells :

```
.right, .left {
height: 500px;
width: 50%;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
font-size: 3em;
}
```

You could also do a vertical transform on the children's content :

http://jsfiddle.net/0sop57yc/

```
span, .about-btn {
display: block; // Chrome apparently doesn't agree with inline-block here
position: relative;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Edit - not sure who added the `width: 100%` for the table but that was a good fix, thanks.

Comment: ! thanks a ton for trying , but i would like to avoid transforms ... i am thinking more in terms of `display:table` solution , but so far , just can't get things to work ! Thanks ! +1 though .

Comment: No problem. Display table is sort of a hacky approach though if it's not a data grid. I guess it's considered common practice (again) because of Bootstrap.

Comment: Browser compatibility is more the reason for its common use, which is a shame really. Vertical alignment without a hint of hack is pretty much impossible in CSS anyway.

Comment: Very much true. In that way the web is still partly a paper design (so to speak).

Comment: @Shikkediel ,  the contents of `<div class="right">` are not aligned vertically , is that how its meant to be ?

Comment: I see what you mean, looks good on Firefox but I'll have to check what's up with Chrome. Added another fiddle in the meantime with table layout by the way. Edit - seems to be an issue with the `span` itself, setting display to block looks like a fix.