# Center Images inside Parent container

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, centering

Want to center images both vertically and horizontally without explicitly setting a height on their parents. I would like the height of the tallest image to be the height of the parent and center all other sibling images.

The final results will look like http://fiddle.jshell.net/4myos5s2/ where the tall image sets the height of the parent.

Using flexbox but still requires defining height for parent: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/vc4cd02a/.

```
div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vw;
}

<div>
    <img alt="No, he'll be an engineer." src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
```

Comment: Try this solution; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height

Comment: @user1012181 thanks! That solution works. I'll post it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**If you want all the containers to be sized to the tallest image, you must set the container div sizes...**

You can use javascript to set the size all your flexbox container divs to the maximum height & width of your set of images.

Then use flexbox to center the images by setting `justify-content:center` and `align-items:center` on the container.

[image]

Example code and a Demo:

```js
$(window).load(function(){

  function log(){console.log.apply(console,arguments);}

  $imgs=$('img');

  // calc maxWidth & maxHeight
  var maxWidth=0;
  var maxHeight=0;
  $imgs.each(function(){
    var img=this;
    if(img.clientWidth>maxWidth){maxWidth=img.clientWidth;}
    if(img.clientHeight>maxHeight){maxHeight=img.clientHeight;}
  });

  // wrap each img in a div with class of 'container'
  $('img').wrap('<div class=container></div>');

  $('.container').css({
    'width':maxWidth+'px',
    'height':maxHeight+'px',
  });  


}); // end $(function(){});
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
.container{
  display:flex;
  margin:10px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  justify-content:center;
}
img{
  flex:0 1 auto;
  align-self:center;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>I'm the tallest image</h4>
<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/character3.png">
<h4>We're all shorter images</h4>
<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/fb.png">
<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/car1.png">
<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/ball1.png">
```

Comment: Found a pure css solution that I'll post. Thank you for your response. Upvote for the effort! :)