# How to vertically align in the middle a clickable image (between <a></a>) inside a div in a responsive manner?

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, vertical-alignment

**QUESTION:**

I have two clickable images inside a div. How can I vertically align them in the middle ?

---

**WHAT I TRIED:**

- [How to vertically align an image inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div)
- [Vertically align an image inside a div with responsive height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height)

---

**CODE:**

CSS

```
.accounts {
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;  
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font: 0/0 a;
}

.accounts:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;  /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
    height: 100%;
}

.accounts a {
    width: 30%;
/*    margin: 20% 5% 0% 5%;*/
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font: 16px/1 Arial sans-serif; 
}

.accounts a img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="accounts">
   <a href="LinkA" target="_blank"><img src="Vendors/Images/GithubLogo.png" alt="Github"></a>
   <a href="LinkB" target="_blank"><img src="Vendors/Images/SOLogo.png" alt="Stack Overflow"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this

```
    <div class="accounts">
        <a href="LinkA" target="_blank"><img src="Vendors/Images/GithubLogo.png" alt="Github"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="accounts">
        <a href="LinkB" target="_blank"><img src="Vendors/Images/SOLogo.png" alt="Stack Overflow"></a>
    </div>
```